# MySQL - count total number of rows in php

Tags: php, mysql

What is the best MySQL command to count the total number of rows in a table without any conditions applied to it? I'm doing this through php, so maybe there is a php function which does this for me? I don't know. Here is an example of my php:

```
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("server.com","user","pswd");
if (!$con) {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

mysql_select_db("db", $con);

$result = mysql_query("some command");
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);

mysql_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50942382/7186739

Answer (score 57, accepted):

```
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("server.com","user","pswd");
if (!$con) {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

mysql_select_db("db", $con);

$result = mysql_query("select count(1) FROM table");
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);

$total = $row[0];
echo "Total rows: " . $total;

mysql_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: What about in PHP 5.3?

Comment: it don't work true with LIMIT in query - this method return real count of array

Comment: **2022: STOP USING MYSQL METHODS, THESE ARE NOT SECURE AND REMOVED FROM PHP! Use MySQLi or PDO instead.

Answer (score 26):

Either use COUNT in your MySQL query or do a SELECT * FROM table and do:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table");
$rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
echo "There are " . $rows . " rows in my table.";
```

Comment: You're first part is correct. I would emit the last part pulling back the entire dataset. In this questions scope, that's a waste of resources for a simple count.

Comment: @George I would not suggest using it either. But as he asked if there was any PHP function that could do it, I just shared the option. Just answering the question.

Comment: And that's fine, however, it's always good to point out potential issues like this when you answer a question. Not only does it help the user understand the differences, it increases the legitimacy of your answer, and the attention it gets. Which means, more points for you! :)

Answer (score 9):

`mysqli_num_rows` is used in php 5 and above.

e.g

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","my_user","my_password","my_db");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

$sql="SELECT Lastname,Age FROM Persons ORDER BY Lastname";

if ($result=mysqli_query($con,$sql))
  {
  // Return the number of rows in result set
  $rowcount=mysqli_num_rows($result);
  printf("Result set has %d rows.\n",$rowcount);
  // Free result set
  mysqli_free_result($result);
  }
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Answer (score 6):

Use [`COUNT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/group-by-functions.html#function_count) in a [`SELECT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html) query.

```
$result = mysql_query('SELECT COUNT(1) FROM table');
$num_rows = mysql_result($result, 0, 0);
```

Comment: Use [`mysql_result`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-result.php) (the best for this instance, IMHO) or one of the similar functions for fetching data from result sets.

Answer (score 6):

you can do it only in one line as below:

```
$cnt = mysqli_num_rows(mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(1) FROM TABLE"));
echo $cnt;
```

Comment: Why are you writing this answer, when there's accepted answer? And this question has been asked in 2011.

Comment: ...using a deprecated library (mysql). use mysqli instead

Comment: that is a horrible answer, sending the entire table across to count rows?

Comment: use the select count(1) from table to get the count and put into a variable

Comment: This answer is wrong. It return always 1 because you count the amount of records returned from the query. Since that you are using an aggregate function like `COUNT` you will get  always an row in the result, and later you count this row thereby you'll get always 1.  Furthermore you are using a deprecated library

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50942382/7186739

Answer (score 4):

use num_rows to get correct count for queries with conditions

```
$result = $connect->query("select * from table where id='$iid'");
$count=$result->num_rows;
echo "$count";
```

Comment: Good but what is `where id='$iid'`?!!!!!!!

Answer (score 2):

for PHP 5.3 using PDO

```
<?php
    $staff=$dbh->prepare("SELECT count(*) FROM staff_login");
    $staff->execute();
    $staffrow = $staff->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM);
    $staffcount = $staffrow[0];


    echo $staffcount;
?>
```

Comment: Good addition. A small enhancement: If you use `$staffcount = $staff->fetchColumn();` you can get rid of the `$staffrow` temporary variable.

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","my_user","my_password","my_db");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

$sql="SELECT Lastname,Age FROM Persons ORDER BY Lastname";

if ($result=mysqli_query($con,$sql))
  {
  // Return the number of rows in result set
  $rowcount=mysqli_num_rows($result);
  echo "number of rows: ",$rowcount;
  // Free result set
  mysqli_free_result($result);
  }

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

it is best way (I think) to get the number of special row in mysql with php.

Comment: This technique has already been answered. Why "special rows"? They are just query result rows.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$conn=mysqli_connect("127.0.0.1:3306","root","","admin");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
$sql="select count('user_id') from login_user";
$result=mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
$row=mysqli_fetch_array($result);
echo "$row[0]";
mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

Still having problem visit my tutorial http://www.studentstutorial.com/php/php-count-rows.php

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql = "select count(column_name) as count from table";
```

Answer (score 0):

It`s better to count rows directly in the database, it is more efficient for large tables.

```
$tableName = 'my-table'
$sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM $tableName";
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc(mysqli_query($conn, $sql));
$row_count = $row['COUNT(*)'];
```

Answer (score -1):

Well, I used the following approach to do the same: I have to get a count of many tables for listing the number of services, projects, etc on the dashboard. I hope it helps.

### PHP Code

```php
// create a function 'cnt' which accepts '$tableName' as the parameter.

 function cnt($tableName){
        global $conection;
        $itemCount = mysqli_num_rows(mysqli_query($conection, "SELECT * FROM `$tableName`"));
        echo'<h6>'.$itemCount.'</h6>';
    }
```

Then when I need to get the count of items in the table, I call the function like following

```php
<?php
  cnt($tableName = 'projects');
?>
```

In my HTML front end, so it renders the count number

- It's to be noted that I create the `cnt()` function as a global function in a separate file which I include in my head, so I can call it from anywhere in my code.

Comment: It is very less optimize than the `COUNT(*)` approach

Comment: Well it can be but I can't get it working while this worked for me, so no issues.