# How to check if MySQL results returned empty in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

How to check MySQL results are empty or not. If MySQL query results are empty then else condition should not be executed.
In case MySQL results in data there & in else condition my error my message is there but it is not showing any error message.
I have tried the following code but not showing any alert or echo message on the screen.

```
<?php
$sql = "select * from hall_search_data_1 where rent BETWEEN '".$_SESSION['amount1']."' AND '".$_SESSION['amount2']."'";
$res = mysql_query($sql);
if (!empty($res)) {
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($res)) {
        // here my data
    }
} else {
    echo "no results found";
}
```

Answer (score 11):

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "myDB";
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

$sql = "SELECT id, firstname, lastname FROM MyGuests";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "id: " . $row["id"] . " - Name: " . $row["firstname"] . " " . $row["lastname"] . "<br>";
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
$conn->close();
?>
```

Comment: Addtionnal Information about this answer :  mysqli_result class have a num_rows method that can be called with an 
Object-oriented style: int|string $mysqli_result->num_rows;
Procedural style: mysqli_num_rows(mysqli_result $result): int|string
Source : https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.num-rows.php

Answer (score 4):

Check number of rows

```
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
$rowcount=mysqli_num_rows($result); 
if($rowcount > 0){ 
  echo "Number of rows = " . $rowcount;
  }
  else
  { 
  echo "no record found"; 
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [mysql_num_rows](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-num-rows.php) to get count of number of rows returned from query.

```
if(mysqli_num_rows($res) > 0)
{
    // rest of your stuff
}
else
{
    echo "No records found.";
}
```

**Note:** mysql is deprecated instead use [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) as seen above

Answer (score 1):

> **Security Tip** First of all stop using the `mysql_*` functions because they are not secure for production and later versions has stopped support for this API. So if accidentally you used those function in production then you can be in trouble.
>
> It is not recommended to use the old mysql extension for new development, as it was deprecated in PHP 5.5.0 and was removed in PHP 7. A detailed feature comparison matrix is provided below. [More Read](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php)

For your answer you have to only check `no of rows` is zero or not
Read this Post at [php documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.num-rows.php#refsect1-mysqli-result.num-rows-examples) with Example.

[mysqli_num_rows](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.num-rows.php)

Answer (score 1):

`mysql_*` API has been removed from PHP long time ago. To access the database you should use PDO. Checking if PDO has returned any results is actually pretty simple. **Just fetch the results and if the array is empty then there was nothing returned from MySQL.**

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM hall_search_data_1 WHERE rent BETWEEN ? AND ?');
$stmt->execute([$_SESSION['amount1'], $_SESSION['amount2']]);
$records = $stmt->fetchAll();
if ($records) {
    foreach ($records as $row) {
        // your logic
    }
} else {
    echo 'No records found!';
}
```

There is also mysqli library and if you are stuck using it you have to do a little more work, but the idea is the same. Fetch all results and if nothing was fetched then it means MySQL returned no rows.

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare('SELECT * FROM hall_search_data_1 WHERE rent BETWEEN ? AND ?');
$stmt->bind_param('ss', $_SESSION['amount1'], $_SESSION['amount2']);
$stmt->execute();
$records = $stmt->get_result()->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
if ($records) {
    foreach ($records as $row) {
        // your logic
    }
} else {
    echo 'No records found!';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If what you mean is the result of query execution = null data (row is found but the content is null). you can do the following:

```
<?php
$sql = "select * from hall_search_data_1 where rent BETWEEN '".$_SESSION['amount1']."' AND '".$_SESSION['amount2']."'";
$res  = mysql_query($sql);
$nres = mysql_query($sql);
$check = mysql_fetch_array($nres);  

if(is_null($check['your_column_id'])){ //this will check one of the columns from the query result
    echo "no results found";
} else {
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($res)) {
        // here data
    }
}
```

OR you can check null data inside while

```
<?php
$sql = "select * from hall_search_data_1 where rent BETWEEN '".$_SESSION['amount1']."' AND '".$_SESSION['amount2']."'";
$res  = mysql_query($sql);

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($res)) {
  if(is_null($row['your_column_id'])){ 
  //this will check one of the columns from the query result
  echo "no results found";
  }else{
     //your data
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `mysql_num_rows();` to check your query return rows or not

```
$sql = "select * from hall_search_data_1 where rent BETWEEN '".$_SESSION['amount1']."' AND '".$_SESSION['amount2']."'";
$res = mysql_query($sql);
$rows=mysql_num_rows($res);
if($rows>0)
{
   echo "data return from query";
}else{

echo "data not return";
}
```

> Note:- mysql is deprecated instead use mysqli or PDO

Comment: Using mysqli_num_rows works when there are no rows in the table.  All the other methods above only work when there is a row in the table.