# how to check empty row in a table

Tags: php

How to check empty row in a table using php?

I tried with this code, but it doesnt work:

```
<?php
ob_start();
session_start();
require 'connection/config.php';
$id = $_GET['id'];
echo $id;
$userid = $_SESSION['userid'];
$sql = "select * from post where id='$id'";
//echo $sql;
$result1 = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
while ($row1 = mysqli_fetch_array($result1)) {
  echo $row1['message'] . "<br>";
  $_SESSION['pid'] = $row1['id'];
  $userid = $_SESSION['userid'];
  echo $userid;
  $a = $row1['id'];
  $sql = "select * from post inner join likenew on post.id=likenew.postid where likenew.postid='$id' and likenew.userid='$userid'";
  $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
  while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    if (empty($row)) { ? >
      < a href = "ative.php?id=<?php echo $row['id'];?>" > ready < /a><?php
    } else { ? >
      < a href = "deactive.php?id=<?php echo $row['id'];?>" > notready < /a><?php
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6655628/mysql-count-total-number-of-rows-in-php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You dont want to use while loop for find number of rows use like this.

```
$sql="select * from post inner join likenew on post.id=likenew.postid where likenew.postid='$id' and likenew.userid='$userid'";
$result=mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
$num=mysqli_num_rows($result)
if($num==0){
    ?> <a href="ative.php?id=<?php echo $row['id'];?>">ready</a> <?php
}else{
    ?> <a href="deactive.php?id=<?php echo $row['id'];?>">notready</a><?php
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);

if(isset($row['description'])) {
    echo "<p>No description</p>";
} else {
    echo '<p>'.$row['description'].'</p>';
}
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: **Flaggers / reviewers:** [For code-only answers such as this one, downvote, don't delete!](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260413/2747593)

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example

```
$sql = "SELECT fname, lname, mname FROM sks_staffs where id = '$a'";
$query = $this->db->query($sql);
  if ($query->num_rows() == 0) 
{
   // Do something
}
```

This will work