# How to get number of rows returned by an SQL select query?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I would like to get the number of lines returned by a select query in PHP. I have the following code:

```
$connection = new mysqli($server_name, $server_login, $server_password, $dbName);

if (!$connection) {
    echo "error";
    die("Connection failed. ".mysqli_connect_error())
}

//...

$command = "SELECT player_id FROM Player WHERE player_login = '" . $login."' AND player_password= '".$password."' ";

$result = mysqli_query($connection, $command);
echo num_rows($result);
```

I also tried with `mysqli_stmt_num_rows()` and `mysqli_num_rows()` but my result is always null (no result actually).

Do you know why?

Comment: try count() function to get no. of rows

Comment: @RahulPawar `count` works on arrays. OP wants number of rows matching the query!

Comment: I think @RahulPawar means the mysql function COUNT

Comment: Is your query actually returning any rows! `print $command;` and then run that direct in mysql to see what is really returned.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL - count total number of rows in php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6655628/mysql-count-total-number-of-rows-in-php)

Comment: @BenHillier I think Rahul mean `select  count()`

Comment: @bub! Yeah! I think you're probably right!

Comment: Incidentally: if this ever returns >1 row, I think you might have some security issues on this site. And login/password forms are big targets for SQL Injection. Look at prepared queries for safety!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are a few ways to get the number of rows returned, the most common ones are to run `COUNT(*)` in MySQL, but there's also `mysqli_num_rows($result)` (not `num_rows()` like you used, unless you created that function yourself). `mysqli_stmt_num_rows()` will only work when you're using `prepare()` instead of `query()`.

In ordre to use `COUNT(*)` you have to run and fetch the query first, while `mysqli_num_rows()` is a constant returned by the MySQLiResult object, which you can use if the query didn't fail.

I modified the piece of code you've got to check if the query actually succeeded, `mysqli_num_rows()` won't work if the query failed.

```
$command = "SELECT player_id FROM Player WHERE player_login = '" . $login."' AND player_password= '".$password."' ";

if ($result = mysqli_query($connection, $command)) {
    echo mysqli_num_rows($result);
} else {
    /* Query failed */
    echo "There was an error with the query: $command";
    echo "<br />".mysqli_error($connect);
}
```

Or you can use `COUNT(*)`, but then you'll have to fetch the results first.

```
$command = "SELECT player_id, COUNT(*) as cnt FROM Player WHERE player_login = '" . $login."' AND player_password= '".$password."' ";

if ($result = mysqli_query($connection, $command)) {
    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
    echo $row['cnt'];
} else {
    /* Query failed */
    echo "There was an error with the query: $command";
    echo "<br />".mysqli_error($connect);
}
```

---

You should also note that this query is vulnerable to SQL injection, you should learn how to use prepared statements with placeholders to protect yourself against that. The [manual on `prepare()`](http://php.net/mysqli-stmt.prepare) is a good place to start with that.

---

You also seem to be storing passwords either in plain-text, or with poor methods (such as `md5` or `sha1`). PHP offer's a built-in function, `password_hash()`/`password_verify()` which you should use. If you're below PHP version 5.5, these functions aren't native, but there's a compability pack which can be used instead.

As a final note, mixing object oriented and procedural code will technically work (as the procedural ones in reality call the object oriented ones), but it's considered bad practice. If you connect with an object, continue to use object-oriented code.

## References

- http://php.net/mysqli-result.num-rows
- http://php.net/mysqli-stmt.prepare
- http://php.net/password_hash

Comment: also curious to knw the reason to dv

Comment: Upvote from me! Answers the question and gives OP a lot of useful information!

Comment: @HarshBarach properly someone that you have criticized their answer before? i was once the victim of that.

Answer (score 5):

```
$command = "SELECT count(*) as numberofrecord, player_id FROM Player WHERE player_login = '" . $login."' AND player_password= '".$password."' ";
```

Answer (score 3):

Very simple solution:-

***Use `$result->num_rows` in below way:-***

```
if ($result = $mysqli->query("SELECT player_id FROM Player WHERE player_login = '" . $login."' AND player_password= '".$password."'")) {
  printf("Select returned %d rows.\n", $result->num_rows);
}
```

Reference:- http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php

***Note:-***

Meanwhile read `prepared statement` and use them to prevent your code from `SQL Injection`.

Also always use `password hashing mechanism` while storing the password (if you used plain password).