# count all data from my database using php

Tags: php, mysqli

```
$count_query = mysqli_query ($con, "SELECT COUNT (*) AS total FROM user  ");
        $row_count = mysqli_fetch_assoc ($count_query);
        echo $count = $row_count["total"];
```

I like to count all data from the database but when i run it in localhost this error

> "Warning: mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be
>   mysqli_result, boolean given in C:\Download\htdocs\Practice\index.php
>   on line 153

"always show im getting rid of that so can you help me?

Comment: Try checking for [mysqli errors](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php) after your query.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL - count total number of rows in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6655628/mysql-count-total-number-of-rows-in-php)

Comment: Change ```COUNT (*)``` to ```COUNT(*)```. Remove the space after COUNT.

Comment: You aren't testing if the query was successful. When it fails, it returns a false, which is what the error message is telling you.

Answer (score 0):

You have an error in your SQL statement. You also are adding spaces between function names and the "(".

```
$count_query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT COUNT(*) AS total FROM user  ");
if($count_query) {
    $row_count = mysqli_fetch_assoc($count_query);
    $count = $row_count["total"];
    echo $count;
} else {
    echo "Query Failed";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sql: SELECT COUNT(*) AS total FROM user;
```

Function count(*) should not contain space