# Fetching No Of Rows In Php

Tags: php

we have a table **usersandgroups** and it has four rows.I am trying to fetch the row count as per group id but it is **returning 1** for every group id but it has many rows......one more point when i remove where clause condition even then it is returning 1...that means it is always **returning 1**.

```
<?php

 require_once("db_connect.php");

 $gp_id = $_POST["GP_ID"];

 $query = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM USER_ANDGROUPS WHERE GP_ID = '$gp_id';";

 $res = mysqli_query($con,$query);


 if(mysqli_num_rows($res)>0)
 {
    $row_cnt = $res->num_rows;
     echo $row_cnt ;
 }
 else
 {
   echo "false";
 }

?>
```

I am trying to fetch the row count as per group id but it is **returning 1** for every group id but it has many rows......one more point when i remove where clause condition even then it is returning 1...that means it is always **returning 1**.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL - count total number of rows in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6655628/mysql-count-total-number-of-rows-in-php)

Comment: Please read up on [SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). Your code is vulnerable to this exploit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`SELECT COUNT(*) FROM` will always return a single row which has the complete record number in itself

Change `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM` to `SELECT * FROM` and you are good to go

***Note:*** Your code is wide open for [SQL INJECTION](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). so use `prepared statements` to prevent from that.

[mysqli::prepare](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php)